# DrawerLayout перекрывает onTouchEvent

Tags: android, drawerlayout, ontouchlistener

Всем привет!
В моем приложении используется onTouchEvent для управления собственными жестами на экране.
После подключения DrawerLayout он стал перекрывать все "onTouch" события.
Какое решение будет более быстрым и правильным для работы и того и другого?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Нашел [такое](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17882255/gestures-not-working-when-using-drawerlayout-in-android-app) решение, пока устраивает.

```
    mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    mDrawerLayout.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() { 
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            if(onTouchEvent(event)){
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```